# Linux head utility reading only one line needs more input to exit

Tags: linux, bash

I need to read from a continuous data stream (pipe, actually), line by line, and I need to exit after the 1st line. RIGHT after the 1st line. Sounded pretty easy but, using "head -n 1", I noticed that I actually need to enter a *second* line before head exits.

Test case:

```
[s@svr1 ~]$ cat | head -n 1    
123    <- I type this first (followed by enter, of course)
123    <- I get this output from head, but the command does no exit
456    <- Then I need to type this for the command to exit and bring me back to the prompt
[s@svr1 ~]$
```

Can someone explain (first and foremost) why it's acting like that, and maybe how I could get what I need?
(and I want to stick to basic Linux/Unix lightweight building blocks. No Perl, Python and such...)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you're using `cat | head -n 1`, which is a [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) and not the same as `head -n 1`. If you do `head -n 1` at the console you get the behavior you want — `head` reads one line, prints it, and exits.

If you do `cat | head -n 1`, then this happens:

1. `cat` reads "123" from its input.
2. `cat` writes "123" to its output.
3. `head` reads "123" from its input (which is connected to `cat`'s output).
4. `head` writes "123" to its output and exits.
5. `cat` reads "456" from its input.
6. `cat` tries to write "456" to its output.
7. `cat` gets `SIGPIPE` because the process on the other side of its output has died.
8. `cat` exits.

`cat` begins another read as soon as it's written "123" to `head`, and it doesn't find out that `head` has died until it tries to write a *second* line to it.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! That explains everything. May I suggest that you replace 'cat writes "456" to its output' with 'cat *tries* to write "456" to its output' because, indeed, the system call is made but the result is not achieved, since the SIGPIPE cancels it (as you say). My usage of cat was solely to demonstrate the issue and I am still stuck with the problem though: a command piped into "head -n 1" won't terminate until it tries to send something else after the 1st line... Would you have any clue on how I can achieve that in a script?

Answer (score 0):

You can close the pipe with <kbd>control-d</kbd>. Then the output buffer is flushed and head gets an EOF and exits before it gets more input.

> [s@svr1 ~]$ cat | head -n 1
>   123
>   123
>   <kbd>control-d</kbd>
>   [s@svr1 ~]$

`head` stops after reading the first line. You can verify it with

> [s@svr1 ~]$ cat | head -n 1

then do a `ps aux | grep -w -e cat -e head`, which yields

> ...  cat
>   ...  head
>   ...  grep -e cat -e head

then enter

> 123
>   123

then do a `ps aux | grep -w -e cat -e head` again, which yields

> ...  cat
>   ...  grep -e cat -e head

et voila, head is gone. So it's not head hanging around, but cat which aborts after receiving a EPIPE, when it tries to write the second line.

Comment: Thanks, but it would not work as the input to head (in my real-life situation) is from another program which does not close the file. The "cat" I used here is just to show the (mis)behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your edit which clears up the case - I should have thought of checking which processes were still alive...

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain (first and foremost) why it's acting like that?

`cat` uses `STDIN` when no file name is specified - so it was waiting on you to either give it that second line or ^D.

You can use
`sed -n 1p filename`
to grab only the first line or `sed '1!d' filename` to delete all but the first line.